# Can i copy administrator role to another user?

Tags: user-roles

can i copy the role of administrator to another user and remove few capabilities not required ?. Basically, i want to have a user with restricted admin privileges.

Answer (score 2):

Give this plugin a try - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/user-role-editor/

Comment: This plugin is great. Create a new role in the plugin and enable all capabilities, which will create a 'copy' of the administrator role, and edit capabilities afterwards. That's how I've done it :)

Answer (score 1):

To inspect what's attached to a current user, you can use my [Current User Deamon Plugin](https://gist.github.com/1104763). *(There's also a version at the repo, but that's a little outdated.)*

Then read a little into [Roles & Capabilites](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities) in the Codex to get a feeling for what's happening.

Then use the [`add_cap()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_cap) function to add single capabilites or play with the role objects (use the data, the plugin shows you) to move capabilities between roles).

Basically it's only *a)* retrieving the roles, *b)* grabbing the capabilites and *c)* add a new role (ex. restricted-admin) object that *d)* get's the reduced capabilities.